# Append Current Stock Stock Price to Historical Prices

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-finance

I'm looking to append the current share price of a stock to the end of a period with changing durations.

My current formula for the historical prices is (where cell B3 is a duration of days to retrieve):
`=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price",TODAY()-B3,TODAY())`

Using the below formulae as shown below returns the current trading price in the same format as the historical prices:
`=ARRAYFORMULA({TODAY(),GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price")})`

Combining the above formulas results in a "#N/A" error:
`=ARRAYFORMULA({GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price",TODAY()-B3,TODAY())},ARRAYFORMULA({TODAY(),GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","price")}))`

How can I append today's current trading price to the retrieved historical range when that range is dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is failing because you are giving `arrayformula()` two expressions when it only expects one. One of the [{ array expressions }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) is also superfluous. It is probably easier to do this with `vstack()`, like this:

```
=vstack( 
  googlefinance("AAPL", "price", today() - B3, today()), 
  { today(), googlefinance("AAPL", "price") } 
)
```

See [vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461).